# How to use template_include hook with form submission?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, hooks, template-include

I'm writing a plugin that uses the template_include hook to use a custom template for a custom post type.  This works with GET requests, but with POST requests, it 404s because the $post variable is null within this hook in POST requests.  How do I fix this so that I can use this custom template for both GET and POST requests?

```
namespace mynamespace;

class MyPlugin {

    public static function template_include($template) {
        global $post;
        var_dump($post); //$post exists for GET requests but is null for POST requests.
        var_dump(get_queried_object()); 
        // Same with get_queried_object.  
        // So for POST requests, I have no way of telling if this is the page of the specific 
        // custom post type that I want to target here.
        if ($post and $post->post_type == 'thing') { // true for GET, false for POST
            return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/thing.php';
        }
        else if (get_query_var('post_type') == 'thing') { // true for GET, false for POST
            return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/thing.php';
        }
        return $template;
    }

}

add_filter('template_include', '\mynamespace\MyPlugin::template_include');
```

Comment: Can't you just use `single-{post_type}.php` per [Theme Developer Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/custom-post-type-template-files/)?

Comment: I would, but this is a plugin, not a custom theme, so I don't think that would work, would it?  If it would work, that would be a nice fallback, but I would prefer to be able to put all the templates into a templates folder instead.

Comment: You could just `POST` an extra variable and check for its presence if `$post` is null.

Comment: That would work, thanks!  I do want to keep my form logic and hooks separate though, ideally, so this is a good backup, but I will keep looking for now.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that $wp->query_vars["post_type"] contains the data I need, regardless of whether the request method is GET or POST.

```
namespace mynamespace;

class MyPlugin {

    public static function template_include($template) {
        global $wp;
        if ($wp->query_vars["post_type"] == 'thing') {
            return plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'templates/thing.php';
        }
        return $template;
    }
}

add_filter('template_include', '\mynamespace\MyPlugin::template_include');
```

Also, it appears that the reason this problem occurred in the first place is because I had named a field in the form with the same name as the custom post type.  If I name the form field something different, then there is no issue.